# Re-installing Ruby

Tags: ruby

I used to have Ruby 1.9.3p194 but after trying to install the latest version it's pretty clear I don't have a fully have ruby anymore! I've tried Homebrew and rvm and neither have worked for me. I'm now trying Mac Ports but trying to install any version of ruby doesn't seem to work and now when I try

```
$ ruby -v
```

I get :-

```
/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0
```

I'm at my wits end with this and whilst I'm not an expert or anywhere close , the simple task of upgrading ruby seems ridiculous, can anyone help?

Comment: To clarify: You get that when you try to install Ruby with Homebrew or you get that when you try to run Ruby after installing it with Homebrew?

Comment: as i've now installed macports I'll have to uninstall macports to give you what happens in Brew ,  one minute

Comment: I'm really just trying to get an accurate picture of what the problem you're running into is.

Comment: shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
chdir: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
shell-init: error retrieving current directory: getcwd: cannot access parent directories: No such file or directory
The current working directory doesn't exist, cannot proceed

Comment: Ok I just reloaded homebrew successfully and then it appeared to install ruby 2.1.0 successfully but when I look for the version number to make sure everything is ok , I get this:-    /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: Argument list too long
/usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: line 6: /usr/local/rvm/bin/ruby: Undefined error: 0

Comment: exactly the same issue as before

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried removing rvm and reinstalling?

```
rvm implode
\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable --ruby
```

You can then install various versions of ruby with rvm

Comment: Many many thanks, that was a lot of hard work but your advice worked!

Comment: @AllisterWhitehead: Yep, your problem was that RVM's Ruby had higher priority in your PATH than the new Ruby versions you were installing, so even though you were successfully installing Ruby, typing `ruby -v` into your console was trying to run the same broken version every time.